# What is byte Message object?

Tags: java, jms

I've a code snippet

```
Message msg = JMS_1.createBytesMessage();
```

This createBytesMessage() method's definition says it returns `byte message object`

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-2239/gfdva/index.html

May I know what it means.? Message's type I can understand, but what it means when it says, byte Message object ? I'm confused with a byte here with Message object.

Can anyone help ..?

Comment: It's a JMS message which can contain arbitrary data (bytes). What the content of the message means depends completely on your application. Since we don't know anything about your application, we cannot tell you what data the message contains and what it means.

Comment: From oracle docs :- A BytesMessage object is used to send a message containing a stream of uninterpreted bytes. It inherits from the Message interface and adds a bytes message body. The receiver of the message supplies the interpretation of the bytes.

Comment: Have a look at the Javadoc for BytesMessage, it has more functionality than the base Message type. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html

Comment: @Jesper, But cant we understand without knowing the Application. At the end its a data structure. Its returning the Message type, and the class which is implementing that interface or Interface itself must be having attribute somewhere of byte's type. Does it makes sense ?

Comment: The `createBytesMessage()` method creates a JMS message object that can contains arbitrary bytes as the content of the message. There's not much more to explain about it; I don't understand exactly what you are asking. (What is unclear for you?).

Comment: @Jesper, In layman's terms, I would say ...Not the instance but the Instance's variable..! That must be somewhere which are holding data (bytes). That's what am assuming....! :)